# question about DTG printing

Tags: digital-printing

I have a treatment I've bee applying to photos (using filters and some other Photoshop adjustments) for use in T shirt designs that will be printed direct to garment by a reputable POD provider. I don't have much experience in this area, so I'd love to get some opinions regarding what the overall print quality will be. Looks as desired to me on screen and not terrible printed on paper from my consumer-level inkjet, but will it print on a shirt clean and crisp or will it just look a little dull and noisy?

[image]

This is obviously just a screenshot - actual file sent to print will be ~ 11x14" @ 300dpi.

Comment: There is no way for anyone here to know what quality once can expect from a print vendor. Ask the vendor for samples.

Comment: I was just asking if anything about the nature of the design that throws up any flags, in general. For example, the fact that it's not a vector image or that it's a photograph that's been manipulated. Those were just random examples - in this situation, I don't know what I don't know. Trying to find out if anyone (with a lit of DTG experience) sees that and has a buzzer go off in their head "That's not going to work well on a t-shirt because XXX".

Comment: If it's digitally printed, I don't see any real problem here. As for what quality you will get, there's no way to know.   Ask your printer for a printed sample perhaps, and ask them what kind of files they will need, what format, or tell them what you already have and ask if it's good enough, etc.

Comment: I actually think this particular item might go well on textiles as any texture of the fabric is in line with the marks in the image. The only obvious thing to note is that white is normally "the color of the paper" and many clothing choices would require that you print the white.